# compare data between 2 tables with multiple same records in each table

Tags: sql-server

Heres the situation... i dont have a unique identifier between tables to do matching, so i am matching on a value that can be present more than one time in both tables.  I am feeling like i have have to assign some value and then remove the record from being available for matching when the next record tries to match.

Table 1 has the following data:

```
MedicationName  ID    Pt   Price  SEQ
Drug1           123   AAA  100.00  1
Drug2           345   AAA  200.00  2

Table 2 
InjectionName   ID    PT   StarDate  EndDate
Drug1           123   AAA  20170101  20991231
Drug1           123   AAA  20160417  NULL
Drug2           345   AAA  20161101  20191231
```

The result should be this:

```
Medication   MedID   Price  Injection  InjID StartDate  EndDate  PT   Seq
Drug1        123     100.00  Drug1     123   20170101  20991231  AAA   1
*NULL         NULL    NULL    Drug1     123   20160417  NULL      AAA   NULL*
Drug2        345     200.00  Drug2     345   20161101  20191231  AAA   2
```

But my result is this:

```
Medication   MedID   Price  Injection  InjID StartDate  EndDate  PT   Seq
Drug1        123     100.00  Drug1     123   20170101  20991231  AAA   1
*Drug1        123     100.00  Drug1     123   20160417  NULL      AAA   1*
Drug2        345     200.00  Drug2     345   20161101  20191231  AAA   2
```

I need to show that the 2nd item from the 2nd table does not have a matching value in table 1 because item 1 already matched against it.

Comment: Can you share the code you have tired? And an explanation of the desired results?

Comment: You will need to use windowing functions on Table1 and Table2 so that only the first record matches.  However, if there is a subsequent match, why do you not want data from Table1 to show?

Comment: @SeanLange at this point only joins because i just havent gotten that far... my code is not really as simple as this but its about as simple as i could make it for illstrative purposes.. i know simple joins are not going to do it, and thought i would have to number the rows in some way... which is exactly what was mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: @RajMore I want all the data from table 1 and all data from table 2 however the 2nd row from table 2 does not have a matching record because the first record from table 2 already matched.  The 2nd record is worth $3k to the MD, need to show it was not entered.  My joins are connecting to the same record as record 1 - if 3 in table 2,  there must be 3 matches in table 1.  I'll take a look at the row_number code and see how i can incorporate it.. as I mentioned.. this is very simplified as there are several other joins to get other data for display.  Thanks. will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Where is your query?  How can we fix your query if it is not given?

Answer (score 0):

You will need ROW_NUMBER to separate rows out.. try this:

```
With Table1 As
(
          Select 'Drug1' MedicationName , 123 ID ,'AAA' Pt ,100.00 Price,1 SEQ
    Union Select 'Drug2' MedicationName , 345 ID ,'AAA' Pt ,100.00 Price,1 SEQ
),
Table2 As
(
          Select 'Drug1' InjectionName, 123 ID, 'AAA' PT, 20170101 StarDate, 20991231 EndDate
    Union Select 'Drug1' InjectionName, 123, 'AAA', 20160417, NULL
    Union Select 'Drug2' InjectionName, 345, 'AAA', 20161101, 20191231
),
Table1_Id As
(
    Select 
        Cast (Row_Number() Over (Partition By MedicationName, ID Order BY MedicationName, Id) as Int) MedicationNumber,
        MedicationName, Id, PT, Price, Seq
    From Table1
),
Table2_Id As
(
    Select 
        Cast (Row_Number() Over (Partition By InjectionName, ID Order BY InjectionName, Id) as Int) InjectionNumber,
        InjectionName, Id, PT, StarDate, EndDate
    From Table2
)
Select *
From Table1_Id T1
Full Outer Join Table2_Id T2
    On T1.MedicationName = T2.InjectionName
    And T1.ID = T2.ID
    And T1.MedicationNumber = T2.InjectionNumber
```